# How do I "pretend" to install a package using pip?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

This feels like such a simple question, but I can't find any reference in the [pip documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/) and [the only question that seemed relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11460681/listing-the-dependencies-of-a-package-using-pip) mentions a flag that has apparently been deprecated since version 1.5 (version 8.1 is current at the time of this writing).

How do I "pretend" to install a package or list of packages using pip, without actually installing them?  I have two separate use cases for this:

- I need to see what packages out of a long (~70 line) requirements.txt are missing, *without actually installing them*; seeing what requirements are already satisfied without installing the missing requirements would satisfy this for me.
- Finding the dependencies for a package that I have not yet installed on my computer, without using something like Portage or Aptitude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is also the pretty useful [`pip-tools` package](https://github.com/nvie/pip-tools) that provides a `pip-sync` tool which you can execute in a "dry run" mode against your requirements file(s):

```
$ mkvirtualenv test_so
New python executable in test_so/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
...
(test_so) $ pip install pip-tools
...
Installing collected packages: six, click, first, pip-tools
(test_so) $ echo "Django==1.6.11" > requirements.txt
(test_so) $ pip-sync --dry-run requirements.txt 
Would install:
  Django==1.6.11
```

Also, here is a partially relevant thread: [Check if requirements are up to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22944861/check-if-requirements-are-up-to-date).

Answer (score 0):

Pip (v.23.2.1) has the [--dry-run](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#cmdoption-dry-run) option. From the documentation:

> Don’t actually install anything, just print what would be. Can be used in combination with --ignore-installed to ‘resolve’ the requirements.

You can it use it as

```
pip install poetry --dry-run
```

This will print normal output without actually installing anything.

Answer (score -4):

Per the pip documentation, the proper way to generate the requirements.txt file is via `pip freeze > requirements.txt`. Hopefully this is what you wanted.